# Moving comments in ruamel.yaml

Tags: python-3.x, yaml, comments, ruamel.yaml

In ruamel.yaml (0.17.16) is it possible to move a comment?  The problem I'm having is that when I load my yaml, if there is a block that is empty except for a comment, the comment is attached to the following block.  But, if I then programmatically add data to the block, the comments now appear after the data they are for.  This is a problem if the comments are directions to a human on how to correctly add data to that same block.  I found the command `move_old_comment` but, it doesn't seem to do anything.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML, tokens, CommentedSeq

inp = """\
# header comment
foo:
  # comment after foo
  # another comment after foo

bar:
  # comment after bar
"""

# variable for working with YAML
yaml=YAML(typ='rt', pure=True)

# Set YAML parameters
yaml.default_flow_style = False
yaml.indent(mapping=2, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.compact(seq_map=True)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

yaml = YAML()
data = yaml.load(inp)

print("Before adding data to 'foo':")
print()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
print()

if (data["foo"] == None):
  data["foo"] = CommentedSeq()

data['foo'].append('blah')

print("After adding data to 'foo':")
print()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
Before adding data to 'foo':

# header comment
foo:
  # comment after foo
  # another comment after foo

bar:
  # comment after bar

After adding data to 'foo':

# header comment
foo:
- blah
  # comment after foo
  # another comment after foo

bar:
  # comment after bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `# comment after foo` occurs after the key-value pair `foo:` , which is equivalent to `foo: null and` foo: ~`in YAML. So if you change the value, it is to be expected that the comment stays in the same place. If you would a comment **at the end of the line** containing`foo:`this would be attached to`foo` and that would
cause the following comments to be combined with that. So you could add an EOL comment to circumvent the problem.

However I think you should circumvent the problem by explicitly providing a (non-empty) value at the place
where the user is allowed change the file. This could be an empty string, an empty list or a single
list item with no value. You would have to
adapt your program to test for that (instead of checking `data['foo'] is None`), and adapt your
comment instructions for
the human editor to that:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
# header comment
foo:
  # comment after foo
  # if you want to edit this, put your values on after a dash on a line of their own
  # maintaining the same indentation. Values which contain non alphabetic/numeric characters
  # should be put between single quotes:  - 'this: would: give an error without quotes'
  -

bar:
  # comment after bar
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
try:
    if data['foo'][0] is None and len(data['foo']) == 1:
       data['foo'][0] = 'blah'
except (IndexError, TypeError):
    pass
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
0.17.16
# header comment
foo:
  # comment after foo
  # if you want to edit this, put your values on after a dash on a line of their own
  # maintaining the same indentation. Values which contain non alphabetic/numeric characters
  # should be put between single quotes:  - 'this: would: give an error without quotes'
  - blah

bar:
  # comment after bar
```

If you really want to move the comment, first dump the `.ca` structure of your target and walk over the keys in
`.ca.items` this is however almost certainly going to break in the next minor version upgrade of `ruamel.yaml`